# Is every element of $G$ of order $p$ conjugate to the following matrix?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, sylow-theory, general-linear-group

> For any prime $p,$ consider the group $G = \text {GL}_2 \left (\Bbb Z / p \Bbb Z \right ).$ Then show that every element of $G$ of order $p$ is conjugate to a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$ where $a \in \left (\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z \right )^*.$

**My attempt** $:$ Here $\left \lvert G \right \rvert = (p^2 - 1) (p^2 - p) = p (p - 1)^2 (p + 1).$  So all the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ are of order $p$ and hence they are all cyclic, generated by any of it's non-identity element. I have found that $\text {ord} (A) = p,$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$ Let $H = \left \langle A \right \rangle$ be the $p$-Sylow subgroup generated by $A.$ Now let $B$ be any other element in $G$ of order $p.$ Then it generates some $p$-Sylow subgroup, say $K.$ By Sylow's second theorem it follows that $H$ and $K$ are conjugates of each other i.e. there exists $P \in G$ such that $P^{-1} A' P = B,$ for some $A' \in H.$ So there exists $0 \lt r \lt p$ such that $A' = A^r.$ But this implies that $B = \left (P^{-1} A P \right )^r,$ for some $0 \lt r \lt p.$ If $r = 1,$ then we are through. What will happen if $1 \lt r \lt p\ $? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hint: compute $A^r$. Show that all the possible $A$s are conjugates to one another (hint : it's linear algebraic more than group theoretic).

Comment: @Mindlack what I note is that $$A^r = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & ra \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ for any $r \in \Bbb  Z.$ Do you mean $$Q^{-1} A Q = A^r$$ for any $r \in \Bbb Z$ and for some $Q \in G\ $ ?

Comment: Yes, with $Q$ depending on $r$ of course, as long as $r$ isn't divisible by $p$.

Comment: Can you please provide a $Q$ for a fixed $r \in \Bbb Z\ $? Thanks.

Comment: Consider diagonal $Q$.

Comment: @Mindlack $Q = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & r \end{pmatrix}$ does the trick. Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116425/discussion-between-phi-beta-kappa-and-mindlack).

Comment: $A$ satisfies the polynomial $x^p-1 = (x-1)^p$, so its minimal polynomial is either $x-1$ or $(x-1)^2$. Since $A$ is not the identity, its minimal and characteristic polynomials are both $(x-1)^2$, and so it has a Jordan canonical form over $\mathbb{F}_p$, with the eigenvalues in the diagonal.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Jordan canonical form of any non-identity element of $H$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$ Hence they are all similar to each other. Am I right sir?

Comment: @Phibetakappa: Indeed. Of course, that assumes you know the relevant linear algebra.